# How can I read data from XML and show them in texboxes in C#

Tags: c#, xml

This is my XML file and I want to enter ID in a textbox and get other data into other textboxes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<Users>
<User Name="aa" Occupation="dd" Date_Of_Birth="123456" NIC="123123" 
ID="79461" />
<User Name="Ali Rasheed" Occupation="Student" Date_Of_Birth="111694" NIC="4550246607037" ID="12661" />
  <User Name="Asif Rasheed" Occupation="Civil Engineer" Date_Of_Birth="241190" NIC="4550346603073" ID="90939" />
  <User Name="Sadaf Sohail" Occupation="Teacher" Date_Of_Birth="112233" NIC="445566677999" ID="72508" />
  <User Name="Shahnaz Bano" Occupation="Retired Principle" Date_Of_Birth="223311" NIC="454564974149" ID="65199" />
  <User Name="Alex" Occupation="Programmer" Date_Of_Birth="111694" NIC="45522002211447" ID="44534" />
</Users>
```

This is my code

```
var data = XElement.Load(@"C:\GenesisSolutionsCRMSBuild12101\XMLDatabase.xml").Descendants("User");
foreach (var textbox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    var value = data.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Attribute("ID").Value == textbox.Name.Replace("txt", "").ToLower());
    if (value != null)
    {
        textBox1.Text = value.Attribute("Name").Value;
        textBox2.Text = value.Attribute("Occupation").Value;
        textBox3.Text = value.Attribute("Date_Of_Birth").Value;
        textBox4.Text = value.Attribute("NIC").Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work, what is the problem?

Comment: I want to read this XML file and display these attributes to textboxes. for instance I enter ID in textbox 12661 so other attributes like name occupation dateofbirth and nic in other textboxes

Comment: What is the _problem_? What are you asking? What does this code do and what answers are you looking for?

Comment: I want to display the attributes of ID 12661 into other textboxes like Textbox1 2 3 4

Comment: That I understand. It's not clear what problem you currently have with this code. Anyway see my answer for a guess...

Comment: @Ali Rasheed, tell us what behavior you are observing when you run your code. e.g. you entered the ID, so after this what is happening there.

Comment: Please provide more details as in what is the problem you're experiencing, this question is kinda vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop over all controls. It's as simple as reading the `Text` property from the ID textbox:

```
var data = XElement.Load(@"C:\GenesisSolutionsCRMSBuild12101\XMLDatabase.xml")
                   .Descendants("User");

// Get the ID the user entered
string id = idTextBox.Text;

var user = data.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Attribute("ID").Value == id);
if (user != null)
{
    textBox1.Text = user.Attribute("Name").Value;
    textBox2.Text = user.Attribute("Occupation").Value;
    textBox3.Text = user.Attribute("Date_Of_Birth").Value;
    textBox4.Text = user.Attribute("NIC").Value;
}
```

You may want to consider renaming the `textBoxN` to something more useful, like `nameTextBox`.